# PHP run as FastCGI connecting with files outside the domain directory

Tags: php, fastcgi

On our Linux server I made a cms that has its files located in `/var/www/vhosts/beheer/aanpassen/`. Every domain that uses this cms has access to it through `http://www.[domain name]/aanpassen/aanpassen/[cms file]`.

This leads to `/var/www/vhosts/[domain name]/httpdocs/aanpassen/aanpassen/` which is a symbolic link to `/var/www/vhosts/beheer/aanpassen/`. In the apache and `nginx` settings I added the following line to make this possible:

> php_admin_value open_basedir /tmp:/var/www/vhosts/beheer:/var/www/vhosts/[domain name]/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/[domain name]/conf

This works fine for `php5.3.27` run as `mod_php`. However I want to change the php settings to `php7.0.32` run as `FastCGI`. With these settings this won't work. No access to files outside the domain scope. Is there a way to make this construction work also for `FastCGI`?

I hope there is. Thanks for your help.